# Current limiting required for float charge?

Tags: current, charge, lm317

I'm trying to make a simple float charge circuit for battery backup of an alarm.

The battery specifications state that a voltage of 13.8 is required for float charging and there is no limit on the current.

My power supply is rated at 13.8v and 2.5a. Presumably I need to regulate the charge current to ensure there is sufficient headroom to run everything else that is connected to the circuit (controllers sensors etc).

I've looked into using an LM317 as a current limiter but from what I've read it will cause a voltage drop and isn't particularly efficient?

Thanks

Comment: you could just add in a cheap buck+boost with adjustable current limiting; a few hundred milliamps is safe and sufficient; you don't want to keep dumping power into a fully-charged LA battery, that can generate hydrogen gas...

Comment: Sorry do you have an example of a compatible "buck+boost"? The batteries are valve regulated from what I've read they can be permanently connected to a power source providing the voltage is kept within the float range?

Comment: it's kind of a vanilla part, but look for a module w/ CC+CV sporting the XL6009, or you want top-of-the-line, an LTC3780. It will keep the output voltage constant no matter (within reason) what the input voltage is.

Comment: Managed to find a unit based on the LM2596S which seems to fit the bill perfectly. I'm not 100% sure I actually need to limit the current but finding it difficult to know how much the battery could draw if discharged significantly. Thanks a lot for your help

Answer (score 2):

How much money and time are you willing to put into this?  I had a similar problem and I solved it with a Deltran Battery Tender from Powerwerx.

Five amp charger:  https://powerwerx.com/battery-tender-0220186gdlwh-power-battery-charger

A cheaper 3/4 amp charger: https://powerwerx.com/battery-tender-0220192-junior-battery-charger

Not a paid endorsement, just a happy customer.  Just make sure that the charger is big enough to provide enough current for the load as well as have enough to top off the battery.  I have both of the models I linked to above, the small one was insufficient to keep up with the load I had so I bought the bigger one.  The small 3/4 amp charger I then used to replace a broken charger for my electric weed trimmer.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, I actually have a couple of motorcycle trickle chargers lying around that I could potentially use. Was just keen to learn if there was a simple way to achieve the same result without buying a charger as it seems all I need to do is limit the max current the battery can use

Comment: There's at least a half dozen ways I can think of to solve this problem, each with their own drawbacks.  I mention the Battery Tenders because they will not overcharge your battery like some trickle chargers could.  Without knowing more about the load, battery, and power supply it's difficult to give a good answer.  My first guess on the solution is what I gave before.  My second guess is that you are over thinking this and you don't need a current limiting circuit.  What's important is that the charger or power supply be able to supply enough current to power the load and charge the battery.

Comment: I decided to connect the battery and charge it at 13.8v whilst monitoring the current consumed and temperature. Its been connected for a couple of hours and is hovering around 0.6A draw with an open circuit voltage of 13.1v. I'd assumed that if the load and discharged battery were connected to the supply in parallel that the battery could use up enough current to starve the other devices. I've subsequently read that the battery will only consume the free current in the circuit, therefore I don't actually need a limiter

Comment: I'm not sure the path you took makes sense but the conclusion sounds logical.  It appears the only current limiting devices you need are fuses, and if they are blowing then something is broken.  I'm a bit concerned that you claim 13.1 volts on an open circuit.  That might indicate a bad power supply, or some miscommunication on what you are doing.  If it works for you then it works for you.

Comment: Agreed, I already have 1A fuses connected in the charging circuit. So far the charger has not used more than 0.6A but I will test with a partially discharged battery and see how much current is drawn. The 13.1 volt reading was taken immediately after disconnecting the charger and from what I understand is in line with the 2.2 volts / cell that I should see immediately after charging. I will measure the resting voltage after 24 hours and make sure it is closer to 2.1 per cell. Thanks a lot for your help